# C# Assign/cast to object fields in a struct

Tags: c#, casting, struct, field

Sorry for this newbie question, I'm very new to C# and it's semantics. I have the following struct:

```
public struct MT5Command{

    public MT5CommandType Type{ get;  set;}

    public AutoResetEvent ThreadWaitHandle { get; set; }

    public object InParam { get; set; }

    public object OutParam { get; set; }

}
```

And this code snippet:

```
MT5Command Cmd = new MT5Command();
Cmd.Type = MT5CommandType.GetServerInformation;
Cmd.ThreadWaitHandle = waitHandle.Value;
attributes = new ServerAttributes();
Cmd.OutParam = attributes;
....
ServerAttributes SrvAttributes = new ServerAttributes();
Cmd.OutParam = (ServerAttributes)SrvAttributes;
```

The last line does not compile: Cannot modify members of 'command' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' 
How is it possible to assign the OutParam field to another ServerAttributes struct?

This is the outer for-each loop:

```
foreach (MT5Command Cmd in mCommandQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks, Juergen

Comment: You need to include your foreach loop in the code snippet. But basically, you're doing something like `foreach (MT5Command foo in bar) { foo.OutParam = ... }`. You can instead use a for-loop and access your collection element directly, eg. `bar[i]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, in this case. You haven't given the full snippet, but I suspect it's something like this:

```
foreach (MT5Command command in someCollection)
{
    // Code as posted
}
```

Now because `MT5Command` is a struct, you're getting a *copy* of whatever value is in `someCollection`. Changing the property almost certainly wouldn't do what you wanted it to anyway. The compiler is protecting you from yourself, by making the `command` variable read-only. You could do this:

```
MT5Command copy = command;
copy.OutParam = SrvAttributes;
```

... but I strongly suspect that's not what you want.

As a rule, it's a *really bad idea* to have mutable structs like the one you've come up with - and it doesn't sound like that should be a struct in the first place.

For more information:

- [My article on value types and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [MSDN guidelines on when it's appropriate to create a struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Comment: I just want to assign a value to a struct. In C++ I would do it with a pointer to this struct. What's the equivalent in C#? Do I have to use unsafe code?

Comment: @Juergen: No, you have to learn that C# and C++ are very different. You probably just want a class here - but it's *really* important that you learn C# as a separate language from C++. You *mustn't* just try to apply C++ idioms to C#; you'll end up with horribly broken code.

Comment: I have passed the MT5Command variables as ref parameters to a queue. So I thought that these structs are passed by reference and I could then later use them. So, if I just make all my structs as classes all problems are gone?

Comment: @Juergen: Chances are you need to read my article on parameter passing too: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html If you make your structs classes then your immediate problems may be gone, but there's still the longer term problem of "hit and hope" coding. You should understand the language you're using, not guess its semantics based on another language. I can't stress enough how important it is to really understand the difference between reference types and value types.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just thought that a struct is a struct anyway ;-) Thanks Jon